# Find out if a specified number of array elements match

Tags: ruby

What's a simple way to write a method for checking if a certain number of array elements match. For example

```
["dog", "cat", "dog", "dog"].has_matching(3) 
# true
```

and

```
["dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"].has_matching(3)
# false
```

Ideally the class of the objects being compared would not matter.

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: *"An example would be if 3 these strings match"* - please be specific.

Comment: Yikes I must be tired...

Comment: @max thank you for the edits, I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a method to `Array`:

```
class Array
  def check_if_minimum_duplicates(min_dup)
    group_by{|el| el }.any?{|k, v| v.count >= min_dup }
  end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
irb(main):006:0> puts ["dog", "cat", "dog", "dog"].check_if_minimum_duplicates(3)
true
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> puts ["dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"].check_if_minimum_duplicates(4)
false
=> nil
```